# LWJGL rendering with VBO on different Systems

Tags: java, opengl, vbo

Im creating a 2D SideScroller game for my thesis. For rendering the environment i want to use Vertex Buffer Objects. At home, everything works fine, but in University i get a similar error message:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x651e3435, pid=964, tid=2988

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [nvoglv32.DLL+0xaf3435]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 U:\Desktop\newWS\Bachelor\Bachelor\hs_err_pid964.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

This error appears, when the first Level is complete, and the next Level is loaded here i call

```
private void init() {
    VBOLandScapeHandler = glGenBuffers();
    VBOTextureHandler = glGenBuffers();
    // VBOTextureHandler = glGenTextures()
    createBuffer();
}

private void createBuffer() {
    landScapeArray = BufferUtils
            .createFloatBuffer(level.getVerticeCount() * 2);
    textureArray = BufferUtils
            .createFloatBuffer(level.getVerticeCount() * 2);
    for (List<LandscapePart> landscapePart : level.getParts()) {
        for (LandscapePart cur : landscapePart) {
            if (cur instanceof Seesaw || cur.belongsToSeesaw()) {
                // landScapeArray.put(new float[] { ((Seesaw)
                // cur).getP5().getX(), ((Seesaw) cur).getP5().getY() });
                continue;
            }
            landScapeArray.put(new float[] { cur.getP1().getX(),
                    cur.getP1().getY() });
            landScapeArray.put(new float[] { cur.getP2().getX(),
                    cur.getP2().getY() });
            landScapeArray.put(new float[] { cur.getP3().getX(),
                    cur.getP3().getY() });
            landScapeArray.put(new float[] { cur.getP4().getX(),
                    cur.getP4().getY() });
            textureArray.put(new float[] { 0, 0 });
            textureArray.put(new float[] { 1, 0 });
            textureArray.put(new float[] { 1, 1 });
            textureArray.put(new float[] { 0, 1 });
        }
    }

    landScapeArray.flip();
    textureArray.flip();
}

public void draw() {
    earth.bind();
    // bind landScape data
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOLandScapeHandler);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, landScapeArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTextureHandler);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, landScapeArray.limit());
    // // Unbind the VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    // // Disable Vertex Arrays (VBOs)
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

At home im using a Geforce gtx 750 ti twin frozr, here in university a Quadro 2000.

Nvidia Driver up-to-date, using immediate mode works fine, but thats no good solution =)

Maybe somehow can get more information in the content of the error report file:

http://www.share-online.biz/dl/3BJUHM7NFGB

Are there any mistakes refilling the VBO?

Comment: how can i check these states? The LWJGL-methods i call dont have a return value ...

Comment: `gl*()` functions do not return an error even in C. You have to call `glGetError()` to check if calls resulted in errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely here:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, landScapeArray.limit());
```

I believe `landScapeArray.limit()` is the number of float values in your buffer. The 3rd argument of `glDrawArrays()` is the number of **vertices** to be drawn. Since you have 2 floats per vertex, you need:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, landScapeArray.limit() / 2);
```

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow as im at home and not at the university ... do you have an explanation why it works at home then? if your answer is correct, than it should just never work ... anyway, thanks

Comment: i cant believe it - this really helped ... thousand thanks!! still not clear why it worked at home then, wouldnt mind if anyone could explain this ... maybe some MMU / MPU issues?

Comment: You were basically asking the GPU to read memory beyond the end of the buffer. The behavior in this case is unspecified. I'm somewhat surprised that you got a client side crash, but all bets are off in cases like this. It's plausible that the driver detected the overrun condition, and intentionally crashed the app. Or for some reason it tried to read the memory on the CPU. But that's all speculation.